# RDS 2012 R2 - Shadow Session error

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-server-2012-r2, session, rds

We use the UI on our Connection Broker frequently to shadow RDS sessions. Occasionally, when initiating a remote session, we get the error "Can't get IPv4 or IPv6 address for VM ".

The connection broker can resolve the VM name to an IP, ping the VM, etc., but will not start a shadow session. The pattern I see is when the host server of the VM does not have an IP listed in the network summary portion of Hyper V, the Connection Broker throws this error. Any time I have a vm with an IP showing in Hyper V, the shadow works fine.

Does anyone know why a Hyper V host would randomly not recognize an IP for a VM?  Please see attached image where the top one gets an error and the bottom one does not. They are the same type of machine, network switch, firewall settings, GP, etc.

[Please see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqwAU.png)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can try to manually run following command to launch a shadow session:
Mstsc shadow:2 /v:vlcsrrr-74 /control /noConsentPrompt

usually session 2 is the first RDP-TCP session on a client, you can run qwinsta on vlcsrrr-74 for double confirm.